# System.Web.HttpContext.Current is thread safe in asynchronous?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
public ActionResult AsyncAction()
{
    Task task = new Task(httpContext => {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = httpContext as HttpContext;
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
        var x = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["x"];
        //To do...Contains IO/NET Write/Read Operation...
    }, System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
    task.Start();
    return View();
}
```

*MSDN* say:

> Any public static members of **System.Web.HttpContext** are thread
>   safe.

In my codes is thread safe?

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: _"A piece of code is thread-safe if it functions correctly during simultaneous execution by multiple threads."_ I don;t see here multiple threads running the same code.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is thread safe (I don't think it is). It does not effect if you can use it with `asynchronous` calls. Also you should NOT use threads with ASP. See Stephen Cleary's Blog post on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is thread-safe but it is strangely written.  Why not write it as:

```
Task task = new Task(httpContext => {
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
    var x = httpContext.Request.Form["x"];
    //To do...Contains IO/NET Write/Read Operation...
}, System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```

In general I prefer to use `Current` as little as possible and instead pass around the context explicitly.  That way your code will work even if it's invoked asynchronously.

Unless your question is specifically about assigning to the `Current` property and having it not be changed by another thread while yours is asleep?  That certainly seems like a safe thing to do, but I can find no documentation to support it and looking at `System.Web` in Reflector it's not obviously impossible (e.g. it's not marked as `TheadLocal`).  To be on the safe side, I would rewrite as above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not thread-safe because you are using the same `HttpContext` concurrently on multiple threads. The docs don't state that this is safe.